# Create an array made of imported arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have stored multiple arrays in an archive.py file, which will increase in number as I add more arrays.

```
#in archive.py

array1 = [a, b, c]
array2 = [x, y, z]
array3 = [1, 2, 3]
```

In my main.py file, I want a for loop that calls a function with each array in archive.py as argument per iteration.
To do that, I would like to import archive.py, and then create a container array in main.py which contains all the arrays in archive. How do I do that?

```
# in main.py
import archive

container = []

for x in archive:
    container.append(x)
```

This one does not seem to work, as 'archive' does not seem to be iterable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

Use [`inspect.getmembers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers):

```py
# main.py

from inspect import getmembers
import archive

arrays = [value for name, value in getmembers(archive) if not name.startswith("_")]
```

#### Explanation

`getmembers(archive)` will return all the members of `archive` in a list of `(name, value)` pairs:

```py
# getmembers(archive)
[
    ("__builtins__", ...),
    ("__cached__", ...),
    ("__doc__", None),
    ("__file__", ...),
    ("__loader__", ...),
    ("__name__", "archive"),
    ("__package__", ""),
    ("__spec__", ...),
    ("array1", ["a", "b", "c"]),
    ("array2", ["x", "y", "z"]),
    ("array3", [1, 2, 3]),
]
```

The names beginning with an `_` should not be imported, so we use `not name.startswith("_")` as a filter:

```py
# [(name, value) for name, value in getmembers(archive) if not name.startswith("_")]
[
    ("array1", ["a", "b", "c"]),
    ("array2", ["x", "y", "z"]),
    ("array3", [1, 2, 3]),
]
```

We need only the values:

```py
# [value for name, value in getmembers(archive) if not name.startswith("_")]
[
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["x", "y", "z"],
    [1, 2, 3],
]
```

### Method 2

Define `arrays` in `archive.py`:

```py
# archive.py

arrays = [
    ["a", "b", "c"],  # array1
    ["x", "y", "z"],  # array2
    [1, 2, 3],  # array3
]
```

```py
# main.py

from archive import arrays
```

Comment: Thank you. Method #1 works wonders, is scalable and more elegant. For educational purpose, can you explain more into details how to read the creation of arrays[ ]? You set 2 variables v and k, where v are the arrays from archive.py and k are their attributes?

Comment: @andy_hopk I have updated my answer. `k` are their names such as `"array1"`.

Comment: All clear. Thanks a lot